# segmentation fault, possible reason: function pointer, multi-thread, stl map, etc

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am new to c++. I don't know why the following code has segmentation fault. Doo() is a class that contain a map<>. You can call Doo::start() to start a while loop thread. And then later call Doo::turnoff() to terminate the thread. I don't know what is wrong with my code. Please help me understand.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <map>
#include <chrono>


using namespace std;

class Doo{
    int id;
    bool _turnoff=false;
    map<int,string> msg;
public:
    Doo(int _id);
    void start(bool (*fptr)(map<int,string>&));
    void turnoff();
};

Doo::Doo(int _id){
    id = _id;
    msg[1]="hello";
    msg[2]="nihao";
    msg[4]="conichiwa";
}

void Doo::start(bool (*fptr)(map<int,string>&)){
    thread m_thr([&](){
        while(!_turnoff){
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
            fptr(msg);
        }
    });
    m_thr.detach();
}

void Doo::turnoff(){
    _turnoff=true;
}

bool hdl(map<int,string>& greet){
    cout<<greet[2]<<endl;
    return true;
}

int main(void){
    Doo d(1);
    d.start(hdl);
    while(1){
        char x;
        cin>>x;
        if(x=='q'){
            cout<<"quit"<<endl;
            d.turnoff();
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled with following command:

```
g++ p3.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread
```

It compiled without any problem.

valgrind result:

```
==18849== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18849== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==18849== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18849== Command: ./a.out
==18849== 
==18849== 
==18849== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==18849==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x68C1700
==18849==    at 0x68C1700: ???
==18849==    by 0x402799: void std::_Bind_simple<Doo::start(bool (*)(std::map<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&))::{lambda()#1} ()>::_M_invoke<>(std::_Index_tuple<>) (in /home/xli1989/Projects/playground/a.out)
==18849==    by 0x4026EF: std::_Bind_simple<Doo::start(bool (*)(std::map<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&))::{lambda()#1} ()>::operator()() (in /home/xli1989/Projects/playground/a.out)
==18849==    by 0x40267F: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<Doo::start(bool (*)(std::map<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&))::{lambda()#1} ()> >::_M_run() (in /home/xli1989/Projects/playground/a.out)
==18849==    by 0x4EF2C7F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==18849==    by 0x53D96F9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==18849==    by 0x56F5B5C: clone (clone.S:109)
```

Comment: Don't see you breaking any of the rules, but it's a good idea to know they exist before you do. [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: It seems you assume that a one second sleep will finish after an earlier one second sleep, but that is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there's a data race on `_turnoff`, so your example will exhibit UB. Keep in mind that *nothing* is atomic by default in C++ so you better use `std::atomic` or synchronize.

---

Now, the problem you are referring to arises from the thread task taking a *reference* to an automatic object (`Doo::msg`) that is allocated by the main thread. As the worker thread is **detached** from it's handle in the main thread, this means that that the main thread will be able to terminate before the worker thread and destroy all of its allocated objects on the stack (main destroys its own stack). This results in the possibility of the worker thread keeping a reference to an object that is destroyed.

After sending the turnoff signal in main, you only wait/sleep the same amount of time as the wait/sleep in the worker thread loop. As a result there is a strong possibility of the worker thread "finishing last" using a dangling reference.

This is usually not a problem as the program will terminate anyway, but Valgrind will still complain.

Answer (score -1):

Problem lies in lambda in `thread m_thr`. You are capturing `fptr` by reference, but this reference is destroyed, once function executes. But thread tries to use reference to destroyed fptr and dying because of segmentation fault.

The solution is simple - capture `fptr` by value, not by reference.

```
thread m_thr([=](){ // changed & to =
    while(!_turnoff){
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
        fptr(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: The object the reference refers to is _not_ destroyed when the function is finished executing. It is a member of `Doo` and will stay alive as long as the instance of `Doo` does so.

Comment: Capturing by value will indeed avoid the dangling reference, but your understanding of why is wrong.